# How P.test(V value) in Titan graph traversal query works?

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Came across a scenario where I need to write a titan query using [GraphTraversal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html) api which has various clauses like in, contains, within etc.

To form the required clauses I am utilising P.within(..), P.inside(..), P.test(..) etc. predicates. Following is an illustration of traversal instance

```
traversal.has("field1", P.within(new String[]{"value1", "value2"})).
            has("field2", P.test((r1, r2) -> {
                    return ((String)r1)).contains((String)r2));
                }, "someVal"));
```

I want to understand how Titan internally evaluates this query?
Does it evaluates all predicates after loading all vertices in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Standard predicates like `P.within` will be optimized whenever possible (in your example, if you would have an index over `field1`, Titan would use it). Custom predicates on the other hand can't be optimized; as you say, Titan will load all vertices into memory and then apply the filter predicate.